# Hover или может как то про другому

Tags: html, css

а как сделать чтобы после того как один раз навел курсор, Hover оставался и не возвращался обратно при убирании мыши ??? То есть происходил один раз ! например картинка черная, при наведении стала белой и потом такой цвет и был и происходило это только с одного первого наведения ! Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько знаю, такое нельзя на чистом CSS сделать. Вот готовый пример с использованием JS: http://jsfiddle.net/262J5/

```js
document.getElementById('your_hover').addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="your_hover">Ну же, наведи на меня!!!</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое это я и искал )